# Missing Cart Information in Magento

Tags: magento

Bit of a strange one but when I go to add products to the cart on my Magento website (I'm using 1.9.3.8) the product information (image, name, etc) no longer shows up in the cart, either the preview when you hover over it or when in the cart itself. (Images in links)

The product is in there as the prices are there and customers have still been able to checkout and go ahead with their orders. But obviously, not having the product information there may confused some so it would be great to get it fixed.

The website has been targeted in a couple of phishing attacks recently so I have password protected some folders and added htaccess files to the affected folders denying access, I don't know if my above problem is anything to do with this but my worry is that in doing this I have accidentally broken the cart and have no idea how to fix it. I have gone back and removed some of the htaccess files but nothing has seemed to fix it.

Any help pointing me in the right direction would be extremely appreciated.

[image: Cart Image 1]

[image: Cart Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago, I met the same case, the information about the product has disappeared on the cart. I changed the base theme to test. I compare the current version with a fresh one. I see some code gone. **So, you need to enable the Magento's path hint to correctly check the PHP code in Phtml files. Maybe they are gone.**